# Is g id needed in SVG

Tags: svg

This is a simple question but I can't find an answer that seems certain.

In an SVG where you'd see something like

```
<g id="Layer_3" data-name="Layer 3"><g id="Layer_3-1" data-name="Layer 1">
```

Is this something the SVG actually needs to have? They look the same when removed so I'm wondering if they're solely for identification?

Comment: Yes, id attribute is same as the one used in other html tags.

Comment: The `<g>` SVG element is a container used to group other SVG elements. Once grouped you can transform the whole group or you can apply a mask or a clipping path to the hole group. Also you can reuse the group with a `<use>` element.  If your SVG is looking the same when you remove those groups you don't need them.

Comment: Interesting, thank you @enxaneta

Answer (score 0):

No they are not required.
Even though if you are re-using same svg on a single page.
For example two SVG's with id="edit" it will cause ADA Compliance issue.